# Can't send secured email from UTL_SMTP Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, email, plsql, oracleforms

```
[PROCEDURE SEND_MAIL(    
 P_FROM    IN VARCHAR ,  
 P_TO      IN VARCHAR ,  
 P_CC      IN VARCHAR ,    
 P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2 ,  
 P_SUBJ     IN VARCHAR,  
 P_MSG     IN VARCHAR2 
)

IS
 conn    utl_smtp.connection ;  
 reply   utl_smtp.reply;  
 err_no number;  
BEGIN  
conn:=utl_smtp.open_connection(host => 'smtp.office365.com',port => 587,    
 wallet_path =>     'file:D:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\owm\wallets\oracle',    
 wallet_password => 'Iectest123',secure_connection_before_smtp => true);    
 exception    
    when others then    
       messagebox(SQLCODE||','||SQLERRM);    
 end ;    
 utl_smtp.helo(conn, lv_mailhost);    
 utl_smtp.STARTTLS(conn);    
 utl_smtp.command( conn, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2    
 ( utl_encode.base64_encode( utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_from))));    
 utl_smtp_SEC.command( conn, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2    
 ( utl_encode.base64_encode( utl_raw.cast_to_raw(P_PASSWORD ))));    
 utl_smtp.mail(conn, p_from);    
 utl_smtp.rcpt(conn, p_to);    
 utl_smtp.open_data(conn);    
 utl_smtp.write_data(conn,'MIME-Version: 1.0'|| chr(13)||chr(10) );    
 utl_smtp_SEC.write_data(conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-6' ||     --iso-8859-6    
 chr(13)||chr(10)); --iso-8859-6    
 utl_smtp.write_data(conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: Cp1256' ||--    ARABIC.AR8MSWIN1256    
 chr(13)||chr(10)); --8bit    

 utl_smtp.write_data(conn, 'From:' ||p_from || chr(13)||chr(10));    
 utl_smtp.write_data(conn, 'To:' ||p_to || chr(13)||chr(10));    
 utl_smtp.write_data(conn, 'Cc:' ||p_cc || chr(13)||chr(10));     
 utl_smtp.write_data(conn, 'Reply-To:' ||p_from || chr(13)||chr(10));    
 utl_smtp.write_data(conn, 'Subject:' ||p_subj|| chr(13)||chr(10));    
 utl_smtp.write_data(conn, chr(13)||chr(10));    
 ---------    
 utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_msg));    
 utl_smtp.close_data(conn);    
 utl_smtp.quit(conn);    

messagebox('send Sucessful');    
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN     
      msgbox(sqlerrm);    

END;][1]
```

when i run the procedure i get error ora-28759 failure to open file
althought the path is right and the DBA gave me permission and full control of the whole folder
The user I'm running the code as can access the wallet path 
I just don't know where is the problem 
is it in the code or on the configuration of the wallet cause i have no experience in the wallet issues

Comment: Should be `wallet_path => 'file:D:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\owm\wallets\oracle'`

Comment: i tried that but still get the same error